# How to change color of textview when changing seekbar android?

Tags: android, textview, spannablestring, android-seekbar

I am using seekbar to change color of textview, but problem is when is click at particular position in seekbar, other position of textview color is not changing.
How to solve this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Here is code.

```
  public class SplashActivity extends Activity {
private TextView textView;
private SeekBar seekBar;
int p = 0, noOfLength;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.test);
    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    seekBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar1);
    textView.setText("Loading.Please wait...");// length of string is 22
    String textLength = textView.getText().toString();
    noOfLength = textLength.length();
    seekBar.setMax(noOfLength);
    seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
                boolean fromUser) {
            try {
                Spannable spannableString = new SpannableString(textView
                        .getText());
                if (progress > p) {
                    p = progress;
                    spannableString.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(
                            Color.YELLOW), 0, progress,
                            Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
                    textView.setText(spannableString);
                } else {
                    p = progress;
                    spannableString.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(
                            Color.GRAY), progress - 1, progress + 1,
                            Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
                    textView.setText(spannableString);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    });

}
```

}

When I am moving seekbar without leaving from start to end and from end to start position, it works but when i click seekbar at particular position, it's not working.

Here is screenshot of issue:

[image]

Comment: Use p not the progress in this spannableString.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(
                            Color.YELLOW), 0, progress,
                            Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

Comment: Why don't you disable user touch on seekbar?

Comment: i tried with p. but still same issue @AvishekDas

Comment: U want to change the full textView color? or a particular position?

Comment: not to fill for entire textview.that can be achieved but i need to fill  each characters while moving seekbar. i achieved but problem is in when placing seekbar(not dragging) at particular position, that's what i mentioned in last lines while posting question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are willing to color single character to color while moving seekbar then put this in onProgressChanged :

```
            try {
                Spannable spannableString = new SpannableString(textView
                        .getText());
                if (progress > p) {
                    p = progress;
                    spannableString.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(
                            Color.YELLOW), progress-1, progress,
                            Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
                    textView.setText(spannableString);
                    spannableString.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(
                            Color.GRAY), 0, progress-1,
                            Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
                    textView.setText(spannableString);
                } else {
                    p = progress;
                    spannableString.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(
                            Color.YELLOW), progress-1, progress,
                            Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
                    textView.setText(spannableString);
                    spannableString.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(
                            Color.GRAY), progress, noOfLength,
                            Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
                    textView.setText(spannableString);
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

or if you want to color all the characters then try this:

```
        try {
                Spannable spannableString = new SpannableString(textView
                        .getText());
                if (progress > p) {
                    p = progress;
                    spannableString.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(
                            Color.YELLOW), 0, progress,
                            Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
                    textView.setText(spannableString);
                } else {
                    p = progress;
                    spannableString.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(
                            Color.GRAY), progress - 1, noOfLength,
                            Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
                    textView.setText(spannableString);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```